# Battery Pack Configuration

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, serial, parallel, power-engineering

I currently am using Li-FePO4 cells in the configuration below (picture):[image]

I'm researching how to build a passive cell balancer for this battery pack. Though I'm getting confused on some specs I'm seeing in data sheets; for example in one of TI's spec sheets it says "# Series Cells (Min)". Now I'm not quite sure how I'd answer that. I know I have 2 cells in series X 3, connected in parallel; but not quite sure how to apply that to that spec. (shown in picture below)
[image]

How would I answer that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IC says 6 cells minimum, you have two, therefore it will not work.

The supply voltage for that IC derived from the batteries has a range of 12v to 70 odd, the 6v from your pack will not be enough.

Comment: Either way, how would I answer that question? Would I say 2 cells in series?

Comment: yes, you'd say 2. As you need 6, it will not work with that IC.